# Fix the height and width of a column in MJML

Tags: mjml

I know that `height` is not a valid argument for `mj-column` but I would like to find a solution for this problem.

I have a mail template I would like to reproduce and don't find how to do it using MJML.

Here is the code that doesn't work :

```
  <mj-section>
    <mj-column width="300">
        <mj-image src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" ></mj-image>
    </mj-column>

    <mj-column background-color=yellow width="300">
    <mj-text mj-class="bigNumber"></mj-text>
    </mj-column>
  </mj-section>
```

It's the `mj-column background-color=yellow` that I would like to render the same on mobile.

When you look [at this gif](https://ibb.co/iEm4YH), you can see that when I resize the window, suddenly the width change and go back to normal. I don't understand why.

I've tried another way using `mj-table` but it doesn't act like I would like it to : put the mj-column below the image on mobile.

Did someone experience something similar and found a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: column widths need a px value. They should be set to width="300px"

Answer (score 0):

I put the `background-color` attribute on the `<mj-section>`.

It did what I wanted.

Sadly, MJML doesn't support any means of making columns equal height. To get the same effect, maybe you can put the same background-color on the section that you put on the shorter of the columns. It looks consistent that way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [mj-breakpoint](https://mjml.io/documentation/#mj-breakpoint). Before breakpoint width heppeneds layout will be desktop, but after breakpoint width it will be `100%` width for all mj-column.

By default mj-breakpoint width `320px`

In your case you need to set `<mj-breakpoint width="300px" />`

Sample: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/HkU5I3TFS